# Aggregation from data.table (R language)

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table `myTable` like this(input):

```
user_id    timestamp  event_id

1 Ann      11115555   Level1Start
2 Serg     11113333   Level1Start
3 Ann      11117777   Level1Complete
4 Ann      11116666   Level1Complete
5 Ann      11112222   Level1Start
```

I need to add the column named `timeInLevel` and calculate time between first two logs Level1Start and Level1Complete.

Output:

```
user_id    timestamp  event_id         TimeInLevel

1 Ann      11115555   Level1Start      4444
2 Serg     11113333   Level1Start      NA
3 Ann      11117777   Level1Complete   4444
4 Ann      11116666   Level1Complete   4444
5 Ann      11112222   Level1Start      4444
```

THX for help!!!

Comment: Where does `4444` come from?

Comment: @mtoto it't timestamp difference between logs №5 №4(11116666 - 11112222). It's first because their timestamp is the smallest. And NA because Serg doesn't have logs with Level1Complete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something like this using `data.table` syntax:

```
dt[, TimeInterval := min(timestamp[event_id == "Level1Complete"]) - 
     min(timestamp[event_id == "Level1Start"]), by = user_id]
#   user_id timestamp       event_id TimeInterval
#1:     Ann  11115555    Level1Start         4444
#2:    Serg  11113333    Level1Start           NA
#3:     Ann  11117777 Level1Complete         4444
#4:     Ann  11116666 Level1Complete         4444
#5:     Ann  11112222    Level1Start         4444
```

Comment: Have this mistake `Type of RHS ('double') must match LHS ('integer'). To check and coerce would impact performance too much for the fastest cases. Either change the type of the target column, or coerce the RHS of := yourself (e.g. by using 1L instead of 1)`

Comment: `data.table` complains because of the missing `Level1Complete` for `Serge`, however the output should still be correct when you run `> dt`.

Comment: sorry it's not working. It's calculate only several users. The rest remain with NA in `TimeInterval`

Comment: Do those users have a `timestamp` with `event_id` = `Level1Complete` ?

Comment: not all people has `timestamp`with `event_id = Level1Complete `

Comment: They just haven't  log with `event_id = Level1Complete`. And In my output they must have NA in `TimeInterval`

Comment: Try wrapping `RHS` inside `as.integer()`.